# How to pull a specific tag?

Tags: git

I have a bare_repo that is cloned to three environments. When I work on dev and complete my work I want to be able to tag it and then ssh into test and pull a specific tag up.

Example: Lets say on DEV I make three commits: 1, 2, 3. And lets say I tag it at 2 `git tag -a 2`. Then I do a git add -u; git commit -m "woo!"; git push --tags. Then I ssh into test and I want to do a `git pull` but I don't want to pull commit 3. I want to pull only everything up to the tag 2. How do I do this?

**EDIT**: An alternative to this would be being able to pull specific commits up from the bare repo to the other clones.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GIT pull/fetch from specific tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964368/git-pull-fetch-from-specific-tag)

Comment: I read that already and I don't think it does.

Comment: I'm interested in the answer as well (how to fetch a specific tag without fetching *all* tags), because fetching *all* tags every time results in a lot of bloat and causes git to `git gc` at the worst possible times (or at least that's what it seems like; it's possible I'm wrong). I wish I could just fetch the tag I'm interested in at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a

`git fetch`

to get all changes from the repo followed by a

`git reset --hard 2`

to get the repository state at this tag.

Comment: This seems like it's how to get to a specific point in time, but not pulling a single change as the OP seems to be asking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this seems a bit hack-y. Is their really no way to do something like a `git pull --tagname` where TEST and PROD would only pull commits from before and up-to a tag?

Comment: I would not consider it as being hacky. That's the way some deployment tools are doing it. If you start merging you always risk to get merge conflicts. Especially as a tag can point to very commit regardless if it back of forward in time of even a different branch.