# Fetch a single tag from remote repository

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-tag, git-fetch

This command fetches **all** tags:

```
git fetch origin --tags
```

This command fetches a specific tag:

```
git fetch origin refs/tags/1.0.0
```

**But** that doesn't let me do:

```
git checkout tags/2.3.18
```

How can I fetch a single tag and then perform a checkout?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

> `git fetch origin refs/tags/1.0.0`

This fails because it doesn't write a local reference: it obtains the remote's `refs/tags/1.0.0`, and any tag object(s), commits, etc., required to go with it; it drops those into `FETCH_HEAD` (as all `git fetch` commands always do); and ... that's it.  It never creates reference `refs/tags/1.0.0` in *your* repository, even though it got everything it needed to do so.

To make it create such a tag if it does not yet exist:

```
git fetch origin refs/tags/1.0.0:refs/tags/1.0.0
```

The name on the right of the colon is the name your Git will use in your repository.  You could turn this tag into a branch named `wacky`, for instance, by naming it `refs/heads/wacky`.  (There's no reason to do this.  I am describing this just for illustration.)

This is a non-forced fetch, so if you already *have* a `refs/tags/1.0.0`, your Git will refuse to update your reference.  If you wish to overwrite any existing `1.0.0` tag, use:

```
git fetch origin +refs/tags/1.0.0:refs/tags/1.0.0
```

If you wish to fetch all tags, with or without overwriting:

```
git fetch origin 'refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'
```

with or without a leading plus sign.  (Note: the quote marks are just to protect the `*` from your shell.  The plus sign may go inside or outside the quotes.  In fact, the quotes themselves can go anywhere as long as they surround all asterisks or other shell meta-characters:

```
refs/tags/'*:refs/tags/*'
```

or you can use backslashes instead:

```
refs/tags/\*:refs/tags/\*
```

In all cases we are just protecting the sensitive asterisk from the shell's "asterisks are tasty, let's eat them" functions.)

Comment: When I tried git seems to fetch not only the tag that I specify, but also all historical tags (up to the specified maybe?). Is there a way to limit the number of fetched tags to 1?

Comment: @Sah: what command, *precisely*, did you run? Using `--no-tags` tells `git fetch` not to automatically fetch "extra" tags that it will otherwise fetch; using `--tags` tells it to fetch *all* tags. You can also set `remote.<name>.tagOpt` in your configuration.

Comment: It was `git fetch origin refs/tags/1.0.0:refs/tags/1.0.0` that I ran. And `--no-tags` solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: OK. Git's tag updates are a bit of a mystery to me: I've dug around in the source code and they are done by special case code, as well as by the normal reference-updating code. The special case code may behave differently in different Git versions. Using `--no-tags` suppresses the special-case code.

Comment: One thing I would add is if you've already done `git fetch origin refs/tags/1.0.0` before you saw the tip about using `git fetch origin refs/tags/1.0.0:refs/tags/1.0.0`, you can still create the tag with the command `git tag 1.0.0 FETCH_HEAD` (assuming you haven't fetched anything else since).

Answer (score 50):

I read all the answers, but there is not yet mentioned one syntactic sugar. If you need to fetch only one tag as a tag (to checkout later) you can write, for instance for `refs/tags/2.3.18`:

```
git fetch origin tag 2.3.18 --no-tags
```

This is shortcut for already mentioned:

```
git fetch origin refs/tags/2.3.18:refs/tags/2.3.18 --no-tags
```

Of course, you may not use `--no-tags` if you need other tags (according to the default behavior) or if you already explicitly set `--no-tag` in the `clone` command or in `tagOpt` config option(`man git-clone`).

```
git fetch origin tag 2.3.18
```

Comment: For reference, this is mentioned in the `git help fetch` manpage description of `<refspec>`.

Comment: And this short cut notation is supported before Git v1.0. https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c04094bc153ef1073524267b4eb49989c7b8ccb

Comment: Does it makes any difference if I add `--depth 1`? So the command looks like `git fetch --depth 1 origin tag 2.3.18 --no-tags`

Comment: also note that wildcards work as expected `git fetch origin tag 2.3.* --no-tags`

Answer (score 4):

When you specify explicit refs to `git fetch`, you need to either provide a mapping in your [refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) or do what you want with the fetched id's recorded in `FETCH_HEAD` yourself.

The advantage to having the no-mapping-provided case do no default processing on the fetched refs is, the no-mapping-provided case does no default processing on the fetched refs.  You might appreciate

```
git fetch origin v2.3.18
git tag v2.3.18 FETCH_HEAD    # ← git tag !$ FE<TAB>
```

when you really only want just the one tag set up in your local repo and not however many dozens of prior tags in the origin repo point into the fetched history.

Comment: You seem to repeat yourself in the 2nd paragraph.