# Pulling a specific tag from remote repository.

Tags: git, tags, version, fetch

How to pull a specific release version from remote repository? I have tried "git fetch" but the fetched tagged doesn't show when I do "git tag".

Comment: `git fetch --tags`? --- I googled your question and found another question on SO which answers it. (See the possible duplicate comment)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch a single tag from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45338495/fetch-a-single-tag-from-remote-repository)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to fetch the tag like this

```
    git fetch origin refs/tags/1.0.0:refs/tags/1.0.0
```

And if you want to fetch and create a new branch to work on, then try this

```
git fetch origin refs/tags/1.0.0:refs/head/my-branch
```

You can further read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45338495/fetch-a-single-tag-from-remote-repository)