# git fetch: how to just pull a pattern of tags

Tags: git, fetch

I want sync all tags which name is ver*, I tried following command but it fetched tags which name is not ver*

```
git fetch --tags --prune --prune-tags --force origin '+refs/tags/ver*:refs/tags/ver*'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points :

- `--tags` is equivalent to adding `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` on your command line, and will fetch all tags

You should drop that option

- by default, `git fetch` will download any tag that points to any commit in the history of the refs you fetch
  e.g: if you have a `osexp-test` tag pointing to a commit which is part of the history of `ver-1.1`, then that tag will also be fetched.

To cancel this beavior, use the `--no-tags` option

```
git fetch --no-tags --prune --prune-tags origin '+refs/tags/ver*:refs/tags/ver*'
```

---

The default behavior is documented in [`git help tag`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_description) (second paragraph of the `Description` section) :

> By default, any tag that points into the histories being fetched is also fetched; the effect is to fetch tags that point at branches that you are interested in. This default behavior can be changed by using the `--tags` or `--no-tags` options or by configuring `remote.<name>.tagOpt`.

Comment: thank you, I tried dropping --tags, `git fetch origin '+refs/tags/xxx*:refs/tags/xxx*'` still fetch all tags, don't why.

Comment: --no-tags works.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54635270/2293666.

Comment: hmm, you are right, I had forgotten about the way tags are fetched

Comment: yeah, the root reason is exactly that the --tags option will fetch all tags, thanks for your help.  Could you please update your answer?, then I will accept it.